# Simple External Database For Android

Tags: android

I am looking for a very hosted database to use for an Android application. Either that or an alternative design approach?

I have a user who wants to manually update a "today's tip" on the app I am making every day. So the database can be very small and simple. Is there a better approach for this, or a good database solution?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a database, you need a place to store a JSON file that changes. Amazon S3 or Backblaze should work for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Sqlite Database solution, see more Info here -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite.